# why is my .gitattribute function not taking out my generated js file

Tags: github, bundle, gitattributes

Like many github users, I would benefit from being able to ignore a specific file from the language statistics. I'm generating/bundling a javascript file from react files and I want to exclude it from the statistics. Here's my .gitattributes file.

```
BlueSlide/static/js/homepage_compiled.js linguist-generated=true
```

I'm having trouble finding many examples on this, but the few that I do find look like this (https://help.github.com/en/articles/customizing-how-changed-files-appear-on-github) so I'm not sure why it's not working. Maybe it just takes time to update the statistics?

Answer (score 0):

apparently the =true part breaks it, despite it being on there documentation... As soon as I got rid of it, it worked

```
BlueSlide/static/js/homepage_compiled.js linguist-generated
```